# Error: error loading plugins: loading plugin /data/ipfs/plugins/go-ds-s3.so: not built with cgo support

Tags: amazon-s3, ubuntu, go, ipfs

After

1. cloning [this repo](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ds-s3)
2. run `make build` (getting as output `s3plugin.so`)
3. run `make install`
4. make the appropriate changes in both `/data/ipfs/config`

```
"Datastore": {
    "BloomFilterSize": 0,
    "GCPeriod": "1h",
    "HashOnRead": false,
    "Spec": {
      "mounts": [
        {
         "child": {
           "type": "s3ds",
           "region": "us-east-1",
           "bucket": "ipfs-test2-node",
           "accessKey": "******",
           "secretKey": "******"
        },
        "mountpoint": "/blocks",
        "prefix": "s3.datastore",
        "type": "measure"
       },
        {
          "child": {
            "compression": "none",
            "path": "datastore",
            "type": "levelds"
          },
```

and `/data/ipfs/datastore_spec`,

```
{"mounts":[{"bucket":"ipfs-test2-node","mountpoint":"/blocks","region":"us-east-1","rootDirectory":""},{"mountpoint":"/","path":"datastore","type":"levelds"}],"type":"mount"}
```

I restarted ipfs `sudo systemctl restart ipfs`

and then while checking that didn't have errors

```
systemctl status ipfs
```

then got

> Error: error loading plugins: loading plugin /data/ipfs/plugins/go-ds-s3.so: not built with cgo support

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [raising an issue](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ds-s3/issues/213) in the GitHub of [go-ds-s3 plugin](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ds-s3), got to know from [Stebalien](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ds-s3/issues/213#issuecomment-999061181) that

> Ah, I see. At the moment, plugins only work on 64bit Linux for the pre-built binaries (because they're built on 64bit linux and building go-ipfs with CGO support for foreign architectures is tricky). For now, you'll have to build go-ipfs from source or use the 64bit version (or use the go-ipfs docker container).
>
> I've filed an issue to support this in our build system ([ipfs/distributions#546](https://github.com/ipfs/distributions/issues/546)).